# Does playframework have some sort of a library to work with guice?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

In my play 2.1 app I was using Guice, but to bind my interfaces to implementations for IoC I was using this library:

https://github.com/sptz45/sse-guice

Is this still needed for play 2.4?  If not, do they have their own helpers that are like sse-guice?

Answer (score 1):

As the [What’s new in Play 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights24) page states:

> Play now supports dependency injection out of the box.

You have the following options for DI in `Play 2.4.x`:

- An implementation that uses Guice out of the box
- An abstraction that allows other JSR 330 implementations to be plugged in
- All Play components can be instantiated using plain constructors or factory methods
- Traits that instantiate Play components that can be mixed together in a cake pattern like style to assist with compile time dependency injection

You can read more about Play’s dependency injection support for [Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection).

Comment: Hi, thanks but I know about that, I'm confused as to how it is actually implemented and wired up.